# Topological sort? without using topsort

Tags: python, list, sorting

I have a python list called activities.py

```
activities = [{'Cost': 10000, 'Duration': 5, 'Name': 'Activity 1', 'Predecessors': None},
{'Cost': 8000, 'Duration': 3, 'Name': 'Activity 2', 'Predecessors': ['Activity 1']},
{'Cost': 2000, 'Duration': 15, 'Name': 'Activity 3', 'Predecessors': ['Activity 2', 'Activity 1']},
{'Cost': 7000, 'Duration': 16, 'Name': 'Activity 4', 'Predecessors': ['Activity 2']},
{'Cost': 5000, 'Duration': 20, 'Name': 'Activity 5', 'Predecessors': ['Activity 4']},
...
```

The list represents a project composed of activities with a set duration and also have a 'Predecessors' key which indicates what activities have to be complete before that activity can start. The list goes up to activity 1001 but I've just included the first 5 lines.

I've already calculated the total time for all of the activities using:

```
def get_total_project_duration(activities: list) -> int:
    total_time = sum(item['Duration'] for item in activities)
    return total_time
    pass
```

However, I want to find out the minimum 'Duration' possible as the list has a 'Predecessors' key which allows for multiple activities to start in tandem to take the least amount of time possible.
I know that this can be done using topological sorting but I wanted to see if there was a way to do the same thing only using the default libraries.

I've already tried using a graph but the dataset is just too big for it to work out

Answer (score 0):

You can write a cached recursive function (e.g. using `functools.cache`) to determine the earliest possible end time for each activity, recursing to the predecessors, if any, and take the `max` of those:

```
from functools import cache

act_dict = {a["Name"]: a for a in activities}

@cache
def earliest_finish(name):
    pred = max(map(earliest_finish, act_dict[name]["Predecessors"] or []), default=0)
    return pred + act_dict[name]["Duration"]

res = {a: earliest_finish(a) for a in act_dict}
print(res)
print(max(res.values()))
```

Output for your five shown activities:

```
{'Activity 1': 5, 'Activity 2': 8, 'Activity 3': 23, 'Activity 4': 24, 'Activity 5': 44}
44
```

This works regardless of the order in which the activities appear in the list. Predecessors are calculated as-needed and then cached.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest storing your activities in a dictionary with their name as key.  You can then loop through the activities, adding a 'Finish' value to each of them based on previously computed 'Finish' values (postponing the activities with incomplete predecessors using a FIFO queue)

Input:

```
activities = [{'Cost': 10000, 'Duration': 5, 'Name': 'Activity 1', 'Predecessors': None},
{'Cost': 8000, 'Duration': 3, 'Name': 'Activity 2', 'Predecessors': ['Activity 1']},
{'Cost': 2000, 'Duration': 15, 'Name': 'Activity 3', 'Predecessors': ['Activity 2', 'Activity 1']},
{'Cost': 7000, 'Duration': 16, 'Name': 'Activity 4', 'Predecessors': ['Activity 2']},
{'Cost': 5000, 'Duration': 20, 'Name': 'Activity 5', 'Predecessors': ['Activity 4']} ]
```

Process:

```
from collections import deque

actDict = { act['Name']:act for act in activities }
links = deque(actDict.values())
while links:
    act   = links.popleft()
    preds = [ pred.get('Finish') for pred in
              map(actDict.get,act.get('Predecessors') or []) ]
    if None in preds:
        links.append(act)
    else:
        act['Finish'] = act['Duration'] + max(preds,default=0)
```

Output:

```
print(actDict)    

{'Activity 1':
   {'Cost': 10000, 'Duration': 5, 'Name': 'Activity 1', 
    'Predecessors': None, 'Finish': 5},
 'Activity 2':
   {'Cost': 8000, 'Duration': 3, 'Name': 'Activity 2', 
    'Predecessors': ['Activity 1'], 'Finish': 8},
 'Activity 3':
   {'Cost': 2000, 'Duration': 15, 'Name': 'Activity 3', 
    'Predecessors': ['Activity 2', 'Activity 1'], 'Finish': 23},
 'Activity 4':
   {'Cost': 7000, 'Duration': 16, 'Name': 'Activity 4', 
    'Predecessors': ['Activity 2'], 'Finish': 24},
 'Activity 5':
   {'Cost': 5000, 'Duration': 20, 'Name': 'Activity 5', 
    'Predecessors': ['Activity 4'], 'Finish': 44}}
```